# For what values of $(a,b,c)$ is $M$ a manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Let $M$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the equations:

$x^2 +y^2 + z^2 = 1$

$ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 = 0$

Where $a, b,$ and $c$ are constants. For what values of $(a,b,c)$ is $M$ a manifold? Is $M$ compact?

Here's my attempt at a solution:

Define $(u,v)$ = $F(x,y,z)$ = $(x^2 +y^2 + z^2 - 1, ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2)$

The Jacobian is computed to be:

$\begin{bmatrix}2x & 2y & 2z\\2ax & 2by & 2cz\end{bmatrix}$

Solving for when the $2 \times 2$ minor matrices are zero we get:

$4bxy - 4axy = 0$

$4cxz - 4axz = 0$

$4cyz - 4byz = 0$

Since the point $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$ is not in the solution set to the original given equations, we can divide by $xy, xz, yz$ respectively.

This results in $a = b =c$.

So my answer is, so long as $a \neq b \neq c$, $M$ is a manifold.

Is this reasoning correct? And how can I show that $M$ is compact? Obviously the unit sphere is compact, but what about it's intersection with $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 = 0$ ?

Can somebody please help? Thank you kindly.

Comment: Well, for one thing, if $a,b,c>0$, then the solution set to the two equations is empty.

Comment: I don't totally agree. Note that if $0<a<b<c$, according to your result $M$ is a manifold. But what you actually get is that $M$ is empty. Note that $(0,0,0)$ isn't a valid point doesn't imply $xy\neq 0$, for example.

Comment: Yes, I can see that now. Is there another way to analyze this problem?

Comment: The only critical points for $F$ seem to be (0,0,0) which is not in the solution set. So wouldn't the regular level set theorem imply that this is a manifold?

Comment: If $a=1,b=-1$ and $c=0$, then the second equation says $(x+y)(x-y)=0$, which is the union of two planes. Intersecting with the unit sphere gives two great circles, which therefore isn't a manifold.

Comment: Yes, I can see that now too. I feel kind of dumb. Can someone please assist me with the is problem? I'm relatively new to the concept of manifolds. Really only learn the definition last week. I'm working with the book Analysis on Manifolds. I'm hoping to try to take real analysis next year.

Comment: If $a=b=c=0$, the second equation is always fulfilled, therefore the solution is the sphere described by the first equation. This definitely is a manifold. Also, if $b=c=0$, the second equation reduces to $x=0$, which describes the $y$-$z$ plane. This intersects with the unit sphere in a circle, which also is a manifold.

Comment: If all three are nonzero, one must have different sign from the others. The second equation then describes a suitably scaled cone aligned with one of the coordinates axes, and the intersection with the sphere is two ellipses, which is a compact manifold (although of course you need to prove it). The interesting case is when some of the constants are zero; you're probably better off checking those manually.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know how to do the "manifold" part yet, here's how to answer the "compact" part. Let $A$ be the unit sphere, $B=\{(x,y,z): ax^2+by^2 + cz^2=0\}.$ Then $M= A\cap B.$ Now $B=f^{-1}(\{0\}),$ where $f(x,y,z) = ax^2+by^2 + cz^2.$ Since $f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, $B$ is the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\},$ hence is closed. Thus $M$ is the intersection of the compact set $A$ with a closed set. Somewhere you learned that such a thing is compact. So $M,$ whether or not it is a manifold, is compact.

Comment: Thank you, this was very instructive and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it seems easier to do it directly:

First of all, the solution set is a manifold if

- $a=b=c=0$ (it's the sphere)
- $a=b=0$ and $c\neq 0$ (it's the unit circle in the $x-y$ plane).

When $a=0$ and $b, c\neq 0$. First of all they have to be of different sign, or the solution set is empty. Now assume $b>0$ and $c<0$ and write

$$ by^2 + cz^2 = by^2 - |c| z^2 = (\sqrt b y - \sqrt{|c|} z)(\sqrt b y + \sqrt{|c|} z).$$

Thus the solution set is a union of two circles with intersection. Thus it is not a manifold.

Lastly, assume all three are nonzero. First of all $a, b, c$ cannot be of the same sign, or the solution set is empty.

Assume $a>0$ and $b, c, <0$. Dividing by $a$ if necessary, we assume that $a=1$. Then

$$x^2 = |b|y^2 + |c| z^2.$$

Put into the first equation gives

$$ (1+|b|)y^2 + (1+ |c|)z^2 = 1, x = \pm \sqrt{1-(1+|b|)y^2 + (1+ |c|)z^2}$$

This means that under the projection $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y)$ the solution curves projected to the ellipse. Since $b, c$ are nonzero, $x$ is nonzero. Thus the projection, while restricted to $x>0$ (or $x<0$) is a diffeomorphism onto its image. This shows that the solution curves is a manifold and is diffeomorphic to two disjoint ellipse.

Comment: Thank you. This was very instructive and helpful.

Comment: All of these answers have been super helpful. How do I decide to whom to award the bounty?

Comment: @WannaBeRealAnalysist You can do whatever you want. I guess both of us don't quite care. We both know that this is your and only your decision.

Comment: I feel you both deserve a piece of the treasure!